# Adding ipython as an interpreter in Pycharm Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, ipython

How does one add ipython as an interpreter in pycharm on ubuntu, since it does not seem to have any directories, where its installed. How can one add it as an interpreter on ubuntu. I've tried looking for it using the following:

```
nafiul@nafiul-Lenovo-B480 ~
  % whereis ipython                                                                                                                               !881
ipython: /usr/bin/ipython2.7 /usr/bin/ipython /usr/bin/X11/ipython2.7 /usr/bin/X11/ipython /usr/share/ipython /usr/share/man/man1/ipython.1.gz
```

Now, I've looked at this, and I've failed to find the the proper ipython directory. All the links above show ipython binaries, and not the actual ipython interpreter directory itself.

Any help regarding this would be very helpful.

Comment: ipython is **not** an interpreter! It uses the installed python and provides a better *interactive session* of **that** interpreter!

Comment: @Bakuriu I see, however, on windows, it behaves like an interpreter. Is there any way to get the ipython console in pycharm?

Comment: The windows package probably contains its own python interpreter bundled but ipython is just an interface to a cpython interpreter. Regarding pycharm, did you read: [this](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/ipython.html) section of the documentation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

FIgured it out. There's no need to add `ipython` separately. If you install `ipython` as a package in the interpreter of your chosing, ipython will *automatically* become the default interpreter of the console.