# How do I get PyCharm to show method signatures and documentation in the Python/IPython console and the editor?

Tags: ipython, pycharm, anaconda

In IPython's QT console (on Windows 7), if I type:

```
import scipy
scipy.zeros(
```

followed by Tab, it displays basic documentation for the method, like its signature, parameters, description, etc. In PyCharm CE 3.4.1, I have IPython enabled as my console, but this doesn't happen. The same is true in the actual editor; if I type this code in the editor, nothing shows up. I don't think this is related to the issue in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21486335/use-ipython-to-get-real-code-completion-in-pycharm) (where PyCharm can't tell the type of something because it's not actually running it) but maybe it is.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

In pycharm you have ctrl-q (or ctrl-j on a mac) for a quick-doc of the function under the cursor.

Comment: Can also select the checkbox **"Show quick doc on mouse move"** in `File>Settings>Editor>General` to show on mouse hover: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2017.1/viewing-inline-documentation.html

Comment: This is impossible to remember... can someone please tell us what the "j" stands for in Mac so we can remember this? What does the "q" stand for in Windows?

Comment: `ctrl  + q` show function parameters but it does not show method parameters on win10, pycharm 2019.

Comment: @andyandy in Pycharm version 2020.2.1 I think it's in `File>Settings>Editor>Code Editing` under `Quick Documentation` section

Comment: *Show quick doc on mouse move* on **MacOS**: **Preferences>Editor>General>Other**

Comment: Doesn't work for dataclasses, but ctrl+p works

Comment: in mac press F1 (default keymap, fn keys default to fkeys instead of volume, etc)

Answer (score 16):

`Ctrl + P` to show method signature (parameters) as a pop-up.

other shortcut keys for pycharm are all available [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/keyboard-shortcuts-by-category.html).

Answer (score 6):

Very old post but it's still a problem.

To see the function docstring, like what TAB in IPython shows, you should press **Ctrl+Shift+I** or go to **View > Quick Definition** while the cursor is within the function name (not between the parenthesis). A pop-up window shows the function docstring including few lines of the function code. However, it's not perfect and may not work in some cases, like *pandas.read_csv()*.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

If you are looking for Mac shortcut it's `Command + P (⌘+P)`, accepted answer's solution didn't work.

Comment: For me in Mac this shows the print dialog (PyCharm Community)

Comment: May it be control+shift+space? For me that shows the function's parameters.