# Is there a way to view parameter information in the PyCharm console?

Tags: python, console, pycharm, code-completion

When editing a file in PyCharm, once you've typed a class/method/function name and an opening bracket, a pop-up appears with the parameter information. You can press <kbd>Ctrl+P</kbd> to make it appear if it doesn't automatically.

However, this doesn't happen when working in a PyCharm Python Console; the parameter information doesn't appear automatically and <kbd>Ctrl+P</kbd> doesn't make it appear.

**Is there a way to make this happen or a setting to turn it on?** Or is it a limitation of the Python console?

Other references:

- The official documentation for viewing reference information doesn't mention the console or discuss limitations between it and the main editor: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/viewing-reference-information.html
- This question is related: [How do I get PyCharm to show method signatures and documentation in the Python/IPython console and the editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26087589/how-do-i-get-pycharm-to-show-method-signatures-and-documentation-in-the-python-i) , but the answers only apply to the PyCharm editor (and possibly the IPython console).

To be clear: I am asking about the "normal" console, *not* the IPython console.

---

I could well imagine it's a limitation of the Python console, except what's puzzling is that the console *can* do basic code completion with <kbd>Ctrl+Space</kbd>, which shows classes/methods/functions that are available in the namespace, including showing a preview of methods/function signatures:

[image: PyCharm console autocomplete]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a known issue, please vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-36610