# pycharm code autocomplete does not work for python console with ipython

Tags: python, autocomplete, ipython, pycharm

autocomplete works in the edit window, but does not work in the python console, which has `Ipython` environment.
However, when I run `ipython` in the terminal window, `Ipython` comes up and autocomplete works.

I am using Pycharm Community version 4.0.6 under windows. 
Someone suggest the autocomplete key binding is ctrl-space, however, i found that in edit window, TAB works for autocompleting.

Comment: Are you trying to change the default ctrl-space bindings in preferences>keymap?

Comment: Is this resolved? I faced the same problem in OS X and PyCharm CE 5.0.2.

Comment: no, i dont think it is resolved

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, namely i wanted to run a different than the default environment in python console. From settings, you can change the interpreter used for python console. (see picture). You should be able to set there the right environment. [Make sure you have installed ipython as a package in the interpreter of your choosing, so ipython will automatically become the default interpreter of the console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20562170/adding-ipython-as-an-interpreter-in-pycharm-ubuntu).

[image]

Last you can set/unset use of ipython from the settings...
[image]